# Echarts - Gaps between stacked bar

Tags: echarts, stacked-bar-chart, apache-echarts

I'm trying to plot a stacked bar graph in echarts but facing a strange issue where there are gaps in between the stacked bars.

Something like the below image.

[Stacked bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGgjb.png)

I am attaching an [echarts demo](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULTsBEAjAhgMYDWA5gE7ACu0AJgMLAA2w52AXDtgDTpY7kApgGcQMYRABugjrDDkqg3hizYwwZpBCzUK_pjXkIpUoLads-AB4RhPPvoPCAFsADus-YuWODYQVZgAMpgAJ5MMpy6vvrYAGYwwRAAXpGwAIwATA6OAL45sLk-qrT4YPgAWhoAtjoF_GqhIGnYENAStDIFRQXYFBC0dXqxhIn4bQAy-LiCTJ4KSvWqEXFgspkADMWOaqCyAMxbSwa4wGDqtZyb27FGpM5rVxvdN9iStlT4TACy-NqcAG0ALqvCKmOhDGKNZqybDCQiUJhzG4NL7GaCwlZrFGqO4PWRHYYNdT_WCEqGnc7AS6wQ44gwQfzVAASgmM-M46XJvlaTIA6gMwM5ZFz6Th_IEQuE0tEYqoEtAkqkRc8iVh8sMesNsFYAII2OxRY7ipotSDVGRi7ClcqyYFW6D4C2w-xqgyOi0TYCEMpQDEWaoDWgRV1Qj2CAAqAWCYRDRrdsQVSrS6QALGKGkm-Wz7o8cKcmJ02BnVNJyJAfUxdUx0bCSaG5QYQPhaLQ2qQ7caYnSu75uY3-P2B5hVcOgcatWGnYIAOJ_AlWtGkaARiAkQ1yBaLg1TGZzePD7CjFjmASkAgACi2ZO4N4yAEoG43sJRyv4XSWDMAy3EWB4LF40A-u-n44M4AyCAA8mWTDzpwcRfMIiwJg0LjuL8Vi7rM8zeL2TiuG43yTNM2GcF4yGHkmQQpCm6Z4TgCTkNUZT-Ke2BIK2uQALRIN83y5AAOhiE7brYq4kJCA5wgROEUVJS7QAKQpYfum6KCJxp4NQdD4OQoRzqS5FWnqBricQG6ys-ClKc4KmyRpCZwiANZgAAclQ1QzKe0BUEiLy9KE-q2J2CaWXK0ItJIXyKE-4ViBIkAwJigirLFULWLYExtDK9ENDW0CCFKcbILlPLHqwsK4LBEmlZgGrDpOUnhh-9HYOGBmyAArEOU6et6vpJQGQYhqBbXTlGkqxjlKE8lRNEipkoGZok2bsnmWmFmY2D0Y1Vk7iRqlhYe5VseQ574Fet7Xte6SPktqjgZ00FmLBhlbrVOBoYR1h2WR70zTsX1EdAv1qXJw4GHNyqctkAOFKNogue5nlbRY20JvVWAgr0SFGCIIUxEdPI2vgBMQ5gAIffw6QAGwAByphsGyZDTTNs_djjpB92Nw_wlO874tMMxsdMAJxs-zVNYFzAuYDz5MU1LmBC6m6QAOydYzEsc_osMK7A8sK_z-vU_Tqapvsqas9rSsZNzOvGybytm3TNNuxLPUKzL-uG-TjtO0L3X7KLWuS7L-jewrvsQ_7JuB1knV0x7Ov8HrUcO7bgeZKLrvJ7b-z2x9sf64H-x091efh9Thfh8XXv051jdq0nNtV9LNf63X5OB2rhzW2HTvKx3RuZw34uW5Xg92-H0fDl3EOBznOeT4Pafk7PA7z8OQs07TLMrwHw9-6P5dLy3A-D6O6dFyfu80_vrdT1f68Z23zuu91dObI_l9HzHt-dRDv3JmKcsDPwhhvRsW8BxCzVukdIhwD4m3AWOeikDYjMXIMQXUQhSZRF2uFWCe5JLk2ku4WQCEmBIR2qNMIMILAEGLK1L6QRQieWYBQxC4NwrCGqBoIUnCqHcN6i0Zk7I0o8mEOUCSFgxH3AkTsRkghqhFWmvrI8zAKoWAAMRxFTHTWgBj0YNQcoTVqJMybHzfhkemwc95IJLn_OeJ8tYPwvk7VMTjN4uJFuLBxCtPEz1flPFW6tNb-PJnTLxUCXEWythEiGgSfbBMHirV27sf4eOiXKaBjZA4bGDqHEBmdskxFyXKeOmRE4JOHJ1UpvhykxCzjnYBntIn1McI0wWDcy4V0ySbJJ19a4n01nAopbSF4dP0F0zmDcm7n2KdYwZL8b7WJ7n3GpA5lkQJSQHMeBTxmgKHkE1ZISx5iwWRM4cUSTnDLWfTO-bjFlTzqbczuACRbf3cXHKZfMAFAM2Xk35WAZkR3pnAhBHsrkwO5mg0amDsG4J0AQqERDSIlXDmQ_8sBKHULhiinkdCWiMIUbEFhbCCyCKQgjPhZxhTwS4aNZqFgvQeARtI4gsI5HClGkolRU0SEQw0SeWE2jcCdUEDTOI-xjEDkxnkAo440C5CAA) which contains all the options I have used.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug, but you have to consider it this way: if you create data for stacked bars, it assumes that you don't have missing values for the base of the stack. However, it should have complained / throw an error not move the gap to neighbouring bars. The solution is to provide zero values for all missing points, which can be easily done programmatically, or even better, provide the data as a full table in the [`dataset`](https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/dataset/#define-data-in-dataset) entry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with echarts(version larger than 5.2.2).

I switched the version to 5.2.2, and there were no gaps between stacked bar.

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp9yg8).

If you do not need to use the newer features, you can consider using version 5.2.2 of echarts, or you can raise an issue on GitHub.